# Python Mapping Arrays

Tags: python, arrays, mapping

I have one array `pat=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]` and a second array `count=[5,6,7,8,9,10,11]`. Is there a way without using dictionaries to get the following array `newarray=[[1,5],[2,6],[3,7],[4,8],[5,9],[6,10],[7,11]]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want inner elements to be list, you can use -

```
>>> pat=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
>>> count=[5,6,7,8,9,10,11]
>>> newarray = list(map(list,zip(pat,count)))
>>> newarray
[[1, 5], [2, 6], [3, 7], [4, 8], [5, 9], [6, 10], [7, 11]]
```

This first zips the two lists, combining the ith element of each list, then converts them into lists using `map` function, and later converts the complete outer map object (that we get from map function) into list

Answer (score 4):

You can just `zip` the lists

```
>>> pat=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
>>> count=[5,6,7,8,9,10,11]
>>> list(zip(pat,count))
[(1, 5), (2, 6), (3, 7), (4, 8), (5, 9), (6, 10), (7, 11)]
```

Or if you want lists instead of tuples

```
>>> [[i,j] for i,j in zip(pat,count)]
[[1, 5], [2, 6], [3, 7], [4, 8], [5, 9], [6, 10], [7, 11]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Without using `zip`, you can do the following:

```
def map_lists(l1, l2):
    merged_list = []
    for i in range(len(l1)):
        merged_list.append([l1[i], l2[i]])
    return merged_list
```

Or, the equivalent, using a list comprehension instead:

```
def map_lists(l1, l2):
    return [[l1[i], l2[i]] for i in range(len(l1))]
```